# java OOP sorting data from objects List

Tags: java, oop

Long story short, main class consist of

```
List<Vehicle> vehicles = new ArrayList<Vehicle>();
Car r1 = new Car(1000, true); ...
```

Cars class is subClass of Vehicles superclass and objects are added to vehicles list. Lastly, the main class calls out

```
System.out.println(Car.findMostExpensive4x4(vehicles).getPrice());
```

SubClass "Car" constructor takes in 2 parameters - price and the 4x4 (boolean)

```
public Car(double pPrice, boolean pfourByFour) {
        super(pPrice);
        this.fourByFour = pfourByFour;
    }
```

The method that is called out in main has to parse data from object list and return that object. But how is this implemented ?

```
public static Car findMostExpensive4x4(List<Vehicle> vehicles) {

}
```

Then, the returned Car object price is found by getPrice method somehow.

```
public double getPrice() {
        return 0;
    }
```

Thank you

Comment: Your `Vehicle` class is probably best suited as an interface that defines the `getPrice()` method.

Comment: Yes, that is a good observation. Deleted getPrice() from Car.

Comment: `"But how is this implemented?"` - I imagine you'd loop through the collection and find the item with the highest price value.  Then return that item.

Comment: As another option, you can use `Collections.sort` with a custom Comparator based on price and then take the first or last element in the collection (depending on how you sort).

Comment: for (int i = 0; i < vehicles.size();) {
  if (vehicles instanceof Car) {
    .... 
  }
I used instanceof because I have also other objects (Trucks) in that list as well.

Comment: What happens if there is no Car in the list? You'll get a NullPointerException trying to invoke null.getPrice().

Comment: That is correct. At the moment I get NullPointerException cause cant catch any Car object. If I am not wrong, there should be two loops. One to loop through list and one to loop through instanceof cars to find only 4x4 cars.

Comment: You need only one loop and an if to test if returned Car is not null. In that case do no print the price, print a message "No car found in list" or similar.

Answer (score 0):

The list passed as argument cannot be a `Vehicle`s list, since a `Vehicle` doesn't know if is 4x4 or not. `Car`s knows it.

You can create a Vehicle interface:

```
interface Vehicle {
    double getPrice();
    boolean is4x4();
}

class Car implements Vehicle { 

    private double price;
    private boolean is4x4;

    public Car(double price, boolean is4x4) {
        this.price = price;
        this.is4x4 = is4x4;
    }

    @Override
    public double getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    @Override
    public double is4x4() {
        return is4x4;
    }

    public static Car findMostExpensive4x4(List<Vehicle> vehicles) {

        if (vehicles == null) return null; //or throw exception
        if (vehicles.isEmpty()) return null; // or throw exception

        double mostExpensivePrice = 0d;
        Vehicle mostExpensive = null;
        for (Vehicle v : vehicles) {
            if (v.is4x4() && v.getPrice() > mostExpensivePrice) {
                mostExpensive = v;
                mostExpensivePrice = v.getPrice();
            }
        }
        return mostExpensive != null? (Car)mostExpensive : null;
    }

}
```

1. It is supposed that price cannot be less than 0. In another case, this solution is not valid.
2. return `(Car)mostExpensive;` will fail if vehicle is not a `Car`.
3. `findMostExpensive4x4` method shouldn't be placed in `Car` class.

This is a fast-thought solution and very ugly, too. You should consider to re-think the design.

Comment: Constructor specified above seems to point that Vehicle is not an interface. It registers the price.

Comment: Unfortunately, the conceptual structure has to remain same. Interface cannot be used and implemented method should be called out from main as it was first shown. Part of the homework. The findMost... in logic should find instanceof Car objects, then check, if 4x4 is true (some of the made objects could be false) and find the biggest price tag car.